# QR code URI scheme to open browser to specific address

Tags: web, mobile, web-applications, qr-code

There are some websites like qr-code-generator which generate qr code that if scanned by a mobile, it opens the browser and redirects the user to a specific address.

I would like to generate programmatically my own qr codes.

For example I can use an API that creates QR codes with my own information.
I just want to know what kind of information should I fill it with, in order to redirect the end user to a specific address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that if you just fill its content with a url for example 'https:www.google.com' then this is enough for a mobile scanner to ask for redirection.

I used the npm library qrcode. Very simple and useful.